# Programmatically add audio files to multiple slides in ppt

Tags: vba, audio, powerpoint

So I have multiple slide decks with about 100 slides that all need audio added to them. I want to programmatically import the audio into the slide deck and heres as far as I could get... make note I am NOT a VB developer, so any help is greatly appreciated. TIA!

```
Const audioFileName As String = "C:\Users\user\audio\Lesson 1 - Slide "
Sub AddMedia()
Dim A As Integer
A = 0

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim CurrentAudioFileName As String
    If Len(A) <= 2 Then 'zero pad that position
CurrentAudioFileName = audioFileName & String(2 - Len(A), "0") & A & ".mp3"
Else
If Len(CStr(A)) <= 2 Then 'zero pad that position
CurrentAudioFileName = audioFileName & String(2 - Len(CStr(A)), "0") & A & ".mp3"
Else
CurrentAudioFileName = audioFileName & CStr(A) & ".mp3"
End If
' This audio is embedded, not linked.
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(CurrentAudioFileName, msoFalse, msoTrue, 350, 10)
    DisplayMediaInfo shp
    A = A + 1
Next
End Sub
Private Sub DisplayMediaInfo(shp As Shape)
If shp.Type = msoMedia Then
    Debug.Print "Embedded: " & shp.MediaFormat.IsEmbedded
    Debug.Print "Linked: " & shp.MediaFormat.IsLinked
End If
End Sub
```

Now when I f8 through the code and come to this piece

```
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(CurrentAudioFileName, msoFalse, msoTrue, 350, 10)
DisplayMediaInfo shp
A = A + 1
Next
```

I get a compile error: Next without a For and the Next is identified by VisualBasic.

Comment: Is this displaying errors?  To help us help you, describe what the code is not doing and on what line it should be doing it (or it gets an error on this line).

Comment: Hey Jimmy, I receive a "Compile Error: Invalid Qualifier" when I try to run the macro. When I go back to VB, the "Sub AddMedia()" code is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: I would add this info to your question above.  If you hit F8, will it let you step through that AddMedia till it hits the line in question.  I think I know where it is and will suggest as answer

Comment: Your code has an `End With` with no corresponding `With`. And you have a `For` with no corresponding `Next`.  (Maybe the two issues are related?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe .AddMediaObject2 needs the slide to be referenced.
Also, the .ToString method is not available in VBA, use CSTR instead.

Try changing,

```
CurrentAudioFileName = audioFileName & A.ToString & ".mp3"
' This audio is embedded, not linked.
Set shp = .AddMediaObject2(CurrentAudioFileName, msoFalse, msoTrue, 350,10)
```

To,

```
If len(CSTR(A)) <= 2 then 'zero pad that position
   CurrentAudioFileName = audioFileName & String(2 - Len(CSTR(A)), "0") & a &  ".mp3"
else
    CurrentAudioFileName = audioFileName & CSTR(A) & ".mp3"
end if
' This audio is embedded, not linked.
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(CurrentAudioFileName, msoFalse, msoTrue, 350,10)
```

As the method is called on the Shapes collection, which is within the current slide(*sld here*) we are referencing!

Also, we need to close a for loop, not a With block in the code.
Instead of `End With`, we could say `Next` (or `Next sld` so you can see how that line works)

Ultimately, that subroutine also needed some fixes to the End statements

```
Sub AddMedia()
    Dim A As Integer
    A = 0

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Dim shp As Shape
        Dim CurrentAudioFileName As String
        If Len(A) <= 2 Then 'zero pad that position
                CurrentAudioFileName = audioFileName & String(2 - Len(A), "0") & A & ".mp3"
        Else
            If Len(CStr(A)) <= 2 Then 'zero pad that position
                CurrentAudioFileName = audioFileName & String(2 - Len(CStr(A)), "0") & A & ".mp3"
            Else
                CurrentAudioFileName = audioFileName & CStr(A) & ".mp3"
            End If
            ' This audio is embedded, not linked.
            shp = sld.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(CurrentAudioFileName, msoFalse, msoTrue, 350, 10)
            DisplayMediaInfo shp
        End If
        A = A + 1

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Jimmy, I see what you mean by using F8. It steps through and highlights the "A" in the bit of code "& A.ToString &"

    CurrentAudioFileName = audioFileName & A.ToString & ".mp3"

Comment: I've edited my answer - I was not even thinking as I work in VB.NET also, but VBA does not use .ToString (actually VBA uses duck typing, so you could just have A there and it'd parse it into that string, but CSTR() is needed sometimes)

Comment: That got me a bit closer! Now I have a Compile error :"End With Without With". When I remove "With" in the code section
    A = A + 1
    End With

I get another Compile Error for the next line stating "For without Next" in the code section
    End Sub

This is probably something extremely basic!

Comment: I've updated the original code to reflect what I currently have.

Comment: `End With` should be a `Next` statement to reitterate the loop.  With block would have been good for `sld`.  `with sld` then your `.addMediaObject` that did not know what it went to, would be assigned to sld.  Will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy! I have updated the original post and the most recent Run-time error up top.

Comment: OH that's because it's a collection of another object within the slide, called `Shapes` and I missed that.

Comment: Another run-time error... I've updated the OP to reflect what I'm getting now :/

Comment: Have you verified the path to the file matches what it's being told to add?  This error may be related to the file, or the path to it.

Comment: Everything looks to be correct, I think the problem is trying to force the numbering of the files in the string to match the content path. The path to the file looks like this "C:\Users\user\audio\Lesson 1 - Slide 01.mp3". So maybe I need to fix the formatting to start with 00 as opposed to 0? I'm not sure.

Comment: That's a matter of adding zeroes into your string to iterate over those files.  I've appended that into my answer.  As far as the original issue though, I think we've got that resolved.

Comment: I agree with that statement! I'm running into the same issue after applying your updated code.

Comment: In these situations, I will put a watch on the variable (CurrentAudioFileName) and compare that to what it's supposed to have.  Why are they not matching is the question?

Comment: Ahh, just did that and I got a value of "C:\Users\user\audio\Lesson 1 - Slide 0.mp3"

Comment: I made a mistake, A has to be a string to measure the length like that.  By default the len is static, which will be 4 bytes.  We must do a .ToString, and see my edit

Comment: CStr sorta does the same thing, but .ToString will give you more verbose exceptions

Comment: Did this help you out?  You're well on your way to VB developer now :D

Comment: Hey Jimmy, sorry for the delayed response!! I applied the new code and now I get a "Compile Error: Invalid Qualifier". When I try to step through the code It highlights the "A" in the "If Len(A.ToString)"

At this point, do you think I can add VB developer to my resume?? :D

Comment: Ohhh I lost my context, .toString is VB.NET.  We need CSTR() in VBA!  See my latest edit, then try again.  We're learning, invalid qualifier means just that "Hey you can't do it with this thing"

Comment: HAHA good to see you still have some humor left with this one! I hope you have some more... now I get another Compile Error: Next without For. It's highlighting the "Next" after A = A + 1

Comment: Hey Jimmy, wanted to reach out and see if you had a chance to take a look at this? Hope all is well!

Comment: We're missing another of those pesky If enders!

Comment: And what would that pesky ender be called?!?! :D

Comment: I feel I've spoiled you here, are you seeing it in my edit? lol

Comment: Hey Jimmy, I agree! You have spoiled me, and I owe you a bunch of beer and BBQ if you're ever in the Austin area! I looked closer at the code and figured out the fix, which appears to have worked in the debugger!! When I run the macro in the .pptm file, nothing is imported. I put a watch on AddMediaObject2 and it returns a value of <Expression not defined in context>. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Haha heck yeah, going to take you up on this someday sir!  That message just means that when you're looking at it, `sld.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(CurrentAudioFileName, msoFalse, msoTrue, 350, 10)` is not within the context for it to see it.  Do you have the watch over the whole statement though - or just part of it?  Also, Macro security is often something that holds me up - you can try turning macro security to low and then see if imports.  When it doesn't, is it giving you any errors?

Comment: Please do!!

I have a watch over part of it. As I'm such a noob, idk how to add a watch to the whole statement :/. I turned the macro security to low and still nothing. It's not throwing any errors or doing anything unusual. Just an fyi I'm on Powerpoint 2016 MSO (10.0.7726.1042) - 64 bit. Not sure if that will help or not

Comment: No problem.  You can select anything you want to watch, highlight the pieces you want to see what they're getting, then right click and add watch from that menu.  But you say the code works fine in debug mode, but when running it, nothing?

Comment: Yeah, it runs through the code and when I put watches on the variable it returns the correct name. I'm just not sure why it's not importing. Would it be possible to send you the ppt file?